# Use variable from inside IF statement

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I'm pulling through some data from a SOAP feed and then displaying it. I want to choose some text to always show if in the feed. But I always want 6 to be shown (the rest if any will be shown using a more button).

To find out if the text I want is in the array I'm using this:

```
<?php
if (strpos($facilitiesstring, 'Reduced Summer Rent Available') !== false)
{
    $number1 = 1; 
    echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">Reduced Summer Rent Available</div></div>'; 
};
?>
```

There is 4 of these. But the text will not always be there, and I still always want 6 to be shown from the feed. I thought about defining a variable with the number 6 and then defining a variable with the number 1 inside each IF statement. I would then subtract each time from the 6, leaving a number of how many to load from the feed to fill the 6 spaces.

But I can't seem to get a variable from inside the IF statement to work outside the statement, is there a better way of doing this? Any help would be great!

Comment: What is _$val_, and what _$facilitiesstring_?

Comment: Just set a counter variable at the top to 0 and increase it in your `if` statements. You will know exactly how many you have at the end.

Comment: @jeroen: Great solution. I'd often, but without succes, tried to count my `ifs` in the past. Can your code also be used with `elses` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The variable scope is not influential in this situation.**

The problem is that `$number1` is defined inside `if` statement, so - if the condition is not satisfied, `$number1` will remain undefined.

You have to init variable before `if` statement:

```
$number1 = 0; // Or you preferred default value;
if (strpos($facilitiesstring, 'Reduced Summer Rent Available') !== false)
{
    $number1 = 1;
    (...)
}
```

This is the *global* problem.

In your specific situation, if you want increment a variable... you have to increment it!

```
$number1 = 0;

foreach() // Or your preferred loop
{
    $number = $number +1; // Or $number++;
    (...)
}
```